# How to loop through 3 dynamic arrays of objects in C# to parse some JSON string?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, database, parsing

Hello I am working on a parser that parses a `JSON` string composed of 3 `dynamic` `array` of objects, the example is listed below.

I dont know the `length` of each array object, my goal is to insert these data in a `database`, so it will be line by line through a specific ID..

My goal now is to find an `algorithm` that parses the data, all the data of the `string` so I can be able to `insert` data line by line to the `database`

```
 "house": {
            "room": [
                20
            ],
            "WC": [
                32,
                7
            ],
            "area": [
                {
                    "floor1": 0,
                    "floor2": 20,
                    "floor3": 30
                }
            ]
        },
```

Foreach(?) > Foreach(?) > Foreach(?)

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted result?

Comment: I a thinking to get the length of each array before starting with the parsing, and then by comparing the sizes I will implement a 'foreach' as follows
parent > child1 > child2

Comment: He meant *show us some code*

Comment: Some code or advices will be useful. Thanks

Comment: No, he meant where's _your_ code? What have you tried so far? Normally questions show some kind of initial effort from the person asking, having tried to solve their problem and failed, rather than merely just asking others to spend their time on it instead. Have you done any research, or tried any code yet? If so please show us and explain what went wrong. IMO writing your own JSON parser is a bit pointless, unless it's an academic exercise? Just use JSON.NET or a similar tool, and it will convert it into any object you like, and then you can use that object like other any C# variable.

Comment: I am asking for advies and not code, you should read the description above before just adding any kind of comment and show that you are SUPERMAN.
I am using the JSON framework, and i am trying a solution ,as I mentioned above, now hope it will works
Thank you

Comment: " I am using the JSON framework"...are you? Well please **show us** then. Right now the question reads like you just want a solution without trying anything, but yet you claim you've got some code using a framework. If that's giving you a problem, we need to look at it. We can't fix code when we can't see it. No-one here is superman, otherwise we could just magically guess the code out of thin air. We are asking you to help us to help you. This site is for specific coding questions by the way, you tend to find you give broken code and get fixed code, we don't go in for vague "advice" very much

Comment: I will add my work soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Newtonsoft.json. I have used JObject according to the json displayed in question above, so if is an array then JArray.Parse can be used.

```
var files = JObject.Parse(line);
var recList = files.SelectTokens("$..house").ToList();
foreach (JProperty prop in recList.Children())
   {
       string key = prop.Name.ToString();
       string value = prop.Value.ToString();
   }
```